# ExtJS 4: Window not sizing correctly on first show

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I can't understand why the first time this code run:

```
var mypopup = Ext4.create('Suidgets.NSConfirmationBox', {
    title: 'Delete',
    message: 'Do you want to delete this row? Do you want to delete this row? Do you want to delete this row?<br>Do you want to delete this row? Do you want to delete this row? Do you want to delete this row?<br>Do you want to delete this row? Do you want to delete this row? Do you want to delete this row?<br>Do you want to delete this row? Do you want to delete this row? Do you want to delete this row?<br>Do you want to delete this row? Do you want to delete this row? Do you want to delete this row?<br>Do you want to delete this row? Do you want to delete this row? Do you want to delete this row?<br>Do you want to delete this row? Do you want to delete this row? Do you want to delete this row?<br>',
    id: 'mypopup',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function() {
            this.doComponentLayout();
        }
    }
});

mypopup.show();
```

it outputs this:
[image]

But once you close it and the next time it is run, it renders the window size perfectly:
[image]

Here's the code of the widget:
https://jsfiddle.net/ardimaunahan/63ofm68o/

I tried several events to trigger doComponentLayout but it still won't take effect: show, beforeshow, activate. However, if you do this via browser console, it adjusts perfectly:

```
Ext4.getCmp('mypopup').doComponentLayout();
```

Could someone tell me why is that happening? Thanks!

**Update 1:**
I checked the difference on the generated HTML, it differs on the height and width of the main window:
[image]

I'm wondering if there's any config in Ext.window.Window that I can use to fix this bug in dimensions.

**Update 2:**
Here's a completely working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ardimaunahan/hcg4p3v4. One has to do Ctrl + F5 on the browser to see the broken popup layout. You also need to hit Esc to close the popup. In Firefox/Chrome, succeeding click to Show popup button makes the layout fine, but in IE it is still broken.

Comment: i tried using 'tpl' for the component inside the window but same result. also checked the difference in the generated html, only the window's height and width differs (see image above)

Comment: Cannot reproduce with just the code provided, I think the CSS is missing. Please make a fiddle that exhibits the problem.

Comment: You can try whether calling doComponentLayout twice or defering doComponentLayout by some milliseconds helps.

Comment: thanks for looking into it Alexander. i'll try to make a fully working fiddle and i'll try your suggestions as well.

Comment: Alexander, calling doComponentLayout twice didn't fix it. And deferring doComponentLayout by some milliseconds is not a good user experience i believe.

Comment: It's not intended as a fix, the question was whether this helps, so that you can pinpoint down the problem.

Comment: understood. thanks for helping. i'm having trouble using fiddle.sencha.com, can't resolve the path for my local resources (CSS). i would like to create a working fiddle for this. any suggestion on how to use it?

Comment: here's a completely working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ardimaunahan/hcg4p3v4/. you might need to do Ctrl + F5 on the browser to see the broken layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the root cause. It's in my HTML tag specifically this line (77-78):

```
     "                                    style=\"padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px\"><img",
     "                                    src=\"https://firnnauriel.duckdns.org/images/icons/popup/info.gif\"><\/td>",
```

The fix would be to set the size of  to 35px by 35px. I found it when I specified the width and height (700 x 500) for the instance of my component. I noticed that when it is first shown, it moves a little to the rightn when the icon appears. It seems that because the image is remotely retrieved, and there's no dimension indicated on the  tag, the Ext framework doesn't know how much to allocate for it initially. But once the icon appears and you hide the window and reopen it, it will now then perfectly compute the final width and height of the window.

Answer (score 0):

I fear that you have to override the `show()` function of your box.

The following seems to work for me:

```
show:function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.doComponentLayout();
}
```

I am not sure whether this works cross-browser, please check before use.

Comment: unfortunately, overriding show() didn't work for me. what browser and its version have you tried? i'm using Firefox 46.0.1 and Chrome 51.0.2704.103 m